# How to get equal segment times using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, split, ffmpeg

I used the following command to split a video into segments :

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 5 -f segment outputfile
```

But I got varying segment times ie. some segments were 5s, some were 2s and others were 8s. How do I correct this ?

Answer (score 2):

You Cant achieve this unless you re-encode this.
ffmpeg will do its best to split close to the time you specified for each segment. This is based in key_frames it will find the closest key frame and cut there. In order to cut exact segments you will need to re encode the whole video.

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -map 0 \
    -segment_time XX \
    -g 9 \
    -sc_threshold 0 
    -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*9)" \
    -f segment output%03d.mp4
```

**NOTE:** XX: Specifies your time.

Comment: Is it not possible at all to do it without re-encoding ?

Comment: Its possible but you will not be able to create segments of same duration. GOP Size would be different. if you can explain your scenario would be easy to provide suggestions.